# How to get the url of the image i just posted on twitter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

I am working on app where i need to post some text with Image to the twitter so with the nes ios twitter API's it's pretty simple and straight forward but now i want to send the url of the image posted in an email. But i can't figure out how to get the url of the image which is showing on twitter.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but one doesn't post images to Twitter but to some 3rd party service (like Twitpic or Lockerz, etc.), right?

Comment: No. With the new twiter api which is inbuilt in ios5 sdk you can actually post images to twitter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new framework doesn't return the response data after posting the tweet with media. Probably you have to use the TWRequest to fetch the newest user_timeline and get the link inside the response data.

But if you use other framework to post tweet with image, you can get the link from the response data when the upload is success

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: Actually we get the response back but it gives us some constructed url and not the actual which we see on twitter. And this url will only be good for the user posted it.